# Xamarin Android Binding referencing Org.Apache.Xml.Security.Algorithms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I am trying to create a Xamarin Android binding library which is referencing org.apache.xml.security.transforms , Org.Apache.Xml.Security.Algorithms

Which reference I have to add to make sure it is working fine?

Sample errors

1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Transforms' matches namespace part 'Transforms'.

\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Apache.Xml.Security.Algorithms.Implementations.IntegrityHmac.cs(150,20,150,31): warning CS0108: 'IntegrityHmac.IntegrityHmacRIPEMD160.GetDHandler()' hides inherited member 'IntegrityHmac.GetDHandler()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: Please attach a MVCE(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and any further information about this binding to the post such as the location of the library, the requirements page, and any other information you might have pertaining to the question.

Comment: Uploaded it.. thanks for pointing out

Comment: These are just warnings it seems. The binding compiles just fine. Is there a class missing that you have noticed? You can alter the name of this type via `Metadata.xml` if you'd like: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Yes, it is missing CLServices.

Comment: Can u help me with one sample that will allow access to CLServices?

Comment: Can you be more specific? `CLServices` is being generated here: [DotPeek Example](http://content.screencast.com/users/JDouglas18/folders/Snagit/media/968328f6-4122-4a46-98a2-c4f958e79cd2/10.02.2016-13.19.png).

Comment: I am not seeing CLService. 
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkQ9G9AdaYOPgacTfHROOl7-aZoB1A 

Is it possible to share the code ?

Comment: I did not change any code, simply ran yours. Make sure your JDK is 1.8 and you aren't changing the compilation target. Finally change the jar to `EmbeddedJar` rather than `InputJar`

Comment: I am setting LibraryProjectZip to aar file and InputJar for jar file. Am I doing correct?

Comment: Got it.. let me try it

Comment: What to set for aar file?

Comment: yes.. I am seeing it now . I will try calling the service in new android project and get back to you :)

Comment: Got it to work .. Thanks @JonDouglas :) How to mark this question as answered?

Comment: Also can you let me know when to use InputJar, LibraryProjectZip, EmbeddedJar options ?

Comment: I will add an answer and you can update and mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not errors, but rather the binding generator giving you a couple of fair warnings.

```
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Transforms' matches namespace part 'Transforms'.
```

This is simply a warning telling you that the name `Transforms` matches part of the previous namespace `org.apache.xml.security.transforms`. Again this isn't a big issue unless these classes are not generating.

```
\obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Apache.Xml.Security.Algorithms.Implementations.IntegrityHmac.cs(150,20,150,31): warning CS0108: 'IntegrityHmac.IntegrityHmacRIPEMD160.GetDHandler()' hides inherited member 'IntegrityHmac.GetDHandler()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

This warning is saying that the `GetDHandler()` implementation of `IntegrityHmac.IntegrityHmacRIPEMD160` is being hidden. Typically this is an issue of obfuscation.

I do have a general binding guide that has most of these aspects covered once you know what you're looking for:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

However after looking over your source, it seems that everything compiles just fine. There are a few notes here:

1. Ensure you are compiling with the correct JDK. I used JDK 1.8 in testing yours, but the documentation of the SDK you are binding to might use a different one.
2. Make sure you are using the correct `Build Action` for your JARs. You can find a recommended use case in our documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/#Build_Actions (`InputJar` does not embed into the .dll and must be found at runtime. Thus you should use `EmbeddedJar`)